# Как убрать ошибку TS2786: 'component name' cannot be used as a JSX component?

Tags: typescript, sdk

В проекте используется gatsby, и в sdk (использовал и vs code и webstorm) подчеркиваются компоненты, выдавая ошибку TS2786. Заметил закономерность, что ругается на компоненты которые используют плагин loadable. Пробовал переустановить глобально typescript, сносил node-modules и редактировал package.json ошибка не уходит. `export const EmptyTable = loadable(() => import('./EmptyTable/EmptyTable'))`
[image: Текст ошибки]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835812/4711135

Answer (score 1):

В общем, история была в том, что у меня создалась папка node-modules в основной директории компьютера (когда в мак запускаешь терминал, он открывается в начальной директории где находятся Documents, Applications и т.д) и по какой-то причине, мой проект обращался к node-modules не в папке, в которой хранился проект, а к этому node-modules внешней директории. После удаления этого внешнего node-modules, это ошибка исправилась. Спасибо за помощь.